# ODP.net general SQL issue and returned Oracle error 3111 - better way of handling?

Tags: oracle, insert, odp.net

While writing a managed insert using ODP.net, if there is any issue whatsoever with the insert (parameter method) I get a very generic error thrown, which I take it is just oracle letting me know it's stopped.  There is no inner trace.

> > ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel

I can look at logs, which is very painful, but is there a way to get the actual real error behind things?  For instance, I traced it down to a char overflow on one column. The source data is messy, and I am doing a lot of scrubbing already, but I am not completely in control of what may appear.  Throwing a workable error that points to the real problem would be so useful :)  Thank you.

Comment: For errors like this where the connection gets killed you need to look at the database side logs.. the ALERT log. The real error will be in there. It could be a database bug.

Answer (score 1):

ok, just needed to step away I guess.  When I wrap this in a try/catch and catch an ORACLEEXCEPTION it gives me much better intel.

```
         try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (OracleException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
```

Message is now this:
    "ORA-12899: value too large for column \"zschema\".\"UPLOAD_V_I\".\"COUNTY\" (actual: 15, maximum: 3)"

Comment: Show us the executed statement.

Comment: Don't add additional information as answers. **Edit** your question

Comment: Hmm, are you referring to my answer Horse with no name?  There's a whole faq section on using the answer my own question button and how it's encouraged.  Why wouldn't I use it as implemented vs. editing the question?  It's not additional info but the answer I found later that day? *boggle*